# how to set application properties to default kafka producer template without setting from kafka producer config bean

Tags: spring-kafka

Here is my application properties defined with properties file:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers = localhost:9090
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

myprojectcommon.util.kafka.producer.max-retry-attempts = 3
myprojectcommon.util.kafka.producer.retry-timeout-ms = 1000
myprojectcommon.util.kafka.producer.retry-timeout-modifier = 2

spring.kafka.producer.max-in-flight-requests-per-connection = 1
spring.kafka.producer.request-timeout-ms = 120000
spring.kafka.producer.acks = all
spring.kafka.producer.linger-ms=100
spring.kafka.producer.connections-max-idle-ms = 180000
spring.kafka.producer.max-request-size = 1000000
```

Here is my kafka producer config :

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties properties;


    @Bean
    public KafkaProducerTemplate kafkaProducerSuccessTemplate() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps  = properties.buildProducerProperties();
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "success_client_id");
        ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps);
        return new KafkaProducerTemplate(producerFactory);
   }

}
```

here is my producer kafka configuration values from console:

```
2021-02-17 18:02:27.483  INFO 127848 --- [-listener-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    linger.ms = 0
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    client.id = success_client_id
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
```

Can some one help on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...linger-ms` is not a valid property.

Boot only supports a subset of properties directly; other properties are set like this...

`...producer.properties.[linger.ms]=`.

See the boot documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka-extra-props

Comment: Thanks @Gary.  All fields are getting updated. its working fine. here is my properties i set   spring.kafka.producer.properties.[max.in.flight.requests.per.connection] = 1
spring.kafka.producer.properties.[request.timeout.ms] = 120000
spring.kafka.producer.properties.[linger.ms]=100

Comment: But still acks property is not being setup properly and still shows acks = -1 in console.
Tried both options spring.kafka.producer.acks = all and spring.kafka.producer.properties.acks = all 

Both options are not working..can you just help me on this?

Comment: That is just the way the kafka-clients renders it; `all` is the same as `-1`.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much.. Appreciate your help!!!