# Unable to set some producer settings for kafka with spring boot

Tags: spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to set the retry.backoff.ms setting for kafka in my producer using the DefaultKafkaProducerFactory from org.springframework.kafka.core. Here's what I got:

```
public class KafkaProducerFactory extends DefaultKafkaProducerFactory {
  
  public KafkaProducerFactory(Map<String, Object> config) {
    super(config);
  }

@Configuration
public class MyAppProducerConfig {

  @Value("${myApp.delivery-timeout-ms:#{120000}}")
  private int deliveryTimeoutMs;

  @Value("${myApp.retry-backoff-ms:#{30000}}")
  private int retryBackoffMs;

Producer<MyKey, MyValue> myAppProducer() {
  Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
  config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, deliveryTimeoutMs);
  config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, retryBackoffMs);
  final var factory = new KafkaProducerFactory<MyKey, MyValue>(config);
  return factory.createProducer(); // calls DefaultKafkaProducerFactory 
}
```

Now when I add the following to my application.yaml

```
myApp:
  retry-backoff-ms = 50
  delivery-timeout-ms = 1000
```

This is what I see in the logging when I start the application:

```
o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:
  delivery.timeout.ms = 1000
  retry.backoff.ms = 1000
```

so the delivery.timeout.ms was set, but the retry.backoff.ms wasn't even though I did the exact same for both.
I did find [how to set application properties to default kafka producer template without setting from kafka producer config bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251756/how-to-set-application-properties-to-default-kafka-producer-template-without-set), but I didn't see either property listed under integrated properties.

So hopefully someone can give me some pointers.

Comment: That code doesn't compile; you can't add code before calling the super constructor; you can't use those fields in the constructor; they are not initialized yet.

Comment: See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.kafka.additional-properties. you definitely don't need to have your own `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` extension.

Comment: You're completely correct Russel. The hashmap part is actually in a different place and passed to the constructor, but I figured it would clutter the code in my question so i moved it to the constructor itself when typing my question. Sorry for that!

Comment: The extending class is used to create an AxualProducer and to have some custom metrics

Answer (score 0):

After an intense debugging session I found the issue. DefaultKafkaProducerFactory is in a shared library between teams and I'm not super familiar with the class since it's my first time touching it.

Turns out the createProducer() call in DefaultKafkaProducerFactory calls another function that is overriden in KafkaProducerFactory which then creates an AxualProducer.
And the AxualProducerConfig always sets retry.backoff.ms to 1000ms.